# Pacifier clips that won’t come off easily

Tags: clothing, safety, magnetism

Our son keeps on pulling his pacifier and losing it.
The clipper seem to be the problem as he can jerk it off easily. Is there a way to make it hard so he doesn’t pull it off easily?

Someone suggested sewing but that is not practical as we change his clothes 3-4 times a day.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of options here, mostly not lifehacks

- use a large safety pin (diaper pin) to pin the ribbon to the baby's clothes (yes, this leaves small holes in them, that's why most people use the clips)
- use a pacifier bib
- clip the clipper somewhere the baby can't reach it such as on the shoulder blade; this increases the chance the baby can't reach the pacifier either but may work for you. Warning: do not lengthen the ribbon in this case; long ribbons are a choking hazard
- every time the baby pulls at or fusses with the pacifier clip, give them something else to play with that distracts them
- attach the pacifier to something else; you can buy small pillows and stuffed animals that have pacifiers sticking out of them

Alternatively, stop trying to attach the pacifier to anything, get a bunch of them, and when one drops you can hand over another. Sometimes "convenient" items just aren't as convenient as people tell you they will be.